# IBM Blockchain Extension Local Fabric startup error

Tags: visual-studio-code, hyperledger-fabric, ibm-blockchain

When I use the **IBM Blockchain Platform Extension** to launch the project, and reported the following error:

```
[2020/2/22 下午12:31:53] [INFO] Starting IBM Blockchain Platform Extension
[2020/2/22 下午12:31:53] [INFO] Attempting to require dependency: grpc
[2020/2/22 下午12:31:53] [INFO] Restoring command registry
[2020/2/22 下午12:31:55] [INFO] Registering commands
[2020/2/22 下午12:31:56] [INFO] Migrating local runtime manager
[2020/2/22 下午12:31:56] [INFO] Initializing local runtime manager
[2020/2/22 下午12:31:56] [INFO] Execute stored commands in the registry
[2020/2/22 下午12:31:56] [INFO] IBM Blockchain Platform Extension activated
[2020/2/22 下午12:32:04] [INFO] connecting to fabric environment
[2020/2/22 下午12:32:04] [INFO] startFabricRuntime
[2020/2/22 下午12:32:04] [INFO] 'generate.cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[2020/2/22 下午12:32:04] [INFO] operable program or batch file.
[2020/2/22 下午12:32:04] [ERROR] Failed to start Local Fabric: Error: Failed to execute command "cmd" with  arguments "/c, generate.cmd" return code 1
```

**Environment：**

- Windows 10
- VS Code v1.38.1
- Node.js v10.15.3
- npm v6.4.1
- docker v19.03.5
- dokcer-compose v1.25.4
- IBM Blockchain Platform v1.0.20

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, Check your **docker** is running or not? If your docker is stopped then this error will throw. And make sure your **IBM Blockchain Platform Extension** library is up to date. If not then reinstall IBM vs code extension.

Hope it will help you:)